# running a gui program in the background

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, user-interface, service

i created a windows service that will run another program. but now i want to run a program that has a gui but in the background so i don't want the gui to be visible. this is the code i used for the [service](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948)

**But i can't edit the gui program**

is there a way to set the gui to hidden or set visible = false from the service program?

the service is a windows service created in c++ using visual studios

i used CreateProcess to start the exe file
here's the code i'm using to run the program from the service:

```
path = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.exe";

STARTUPINFO info={sizeof(info)};
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
if (CreateProcess(path, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    ::WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
}
```

is it possible to hide a gui without editing the program itself?

Comment: I guess this is for Windows...

Answer (score 0):

The closest you are likely to get will be setting the `wShowWindow` member of the STARTUPINFO structure. Even then it will only work if the application honors the `nCmdShow` parameter in `WinMain`.

```
STARTUPINFO info = {0};

info.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
info.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

if (CreateProcess(path, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: i can't access the code of the gui program. i did not create it so i can't check the parameters

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean

Comment: It seems like you haven't tried it as a workable solution. That means you don't know if it will work or not. Since you don't have access to the source code you won't know until you try.

Comment: i get this error: error C2039: 'flags' : is not a member of '_STARTUPINFOW'

Comment: thanks for the code it compiles now. i tested it with the program i want to run and it doesn't hide the window but if i test it with notepad it hides that no problem

Comment: Because _it will only work if the application honors the `nCmdShow` parameter in `WinMain`_

Comment: but i can't check if the application honors the nCmdShow parameter in WinMain because i don't have access to the code